# How to pass Data between Tabs in Xamarin forms Prism based-app

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Say I have TabbedPage with two pages :

```
 <TabbedPage ... x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyTabbedPage" ... >
 <TabbedPage.Children>
   <local:PageA/>
   <local:PageB/>
 </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

How I can Pass Data from PageA to PageB (**From PageAViewModel to PageBViewModel**)
I implemented INavigationAware interface and try to use OnNavigationTo(...) but  without success! OnNavigatedTo(...) never be called, OnNavigatedTo will be invoked on the TabbedPage and only the SELECTED TAB.

I wonder if there is a solution for passing data each time I switch from tabA to tabB ?

**MORE INFOS**

Say that I have a list of a customer in the PageA, do some filtering, I want to pass the filtered list of a customers to the PageB to do more actions
How I can perform this using prism? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Going through the tabs will not trigger the Navigation events for PRISM, would suggest you just use a PubSubEvent to tell what you have filtered in tabA and tabB subscribes to it

Comment: @Depechie yes, good idea I completely forgot IEventAggregator :) thanks man.

Comment: Sharing context between Xamarin.Forms TabbedPages using Prism and NavigationParameters : https://taubensee.net/sharing-context-between-xamarinforms-tabbedpages-using-prism-and-navigationparameters/